# Getting Error - QUOTA_BYTES_PER_ITEM when saving a rule in Requestly

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, web-development, headers, requestly

I noticed that while setting a Modify Header rule in [Requestly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa) and when the header values are very large, header rule is not getting saved.

E.g. would be a 7K header value

Any workaround or bug reports for this?

Error - `QUOTA_BYTES_PER_ITEM` seems to be thrown in the browser console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are seeing is because in Requestly, are using `sync storage` to store the rules which means your rules will be synced across devices if you are logged into chrome but that comes with certain restrictions. You can read about Sync Storage here on [Chrome dev docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage)

You are hitting one of them. Here's the solution:-

1. Go to https://app.requestly.in/settings
2. Select Local Storage to store your rules

Please note once you choose local storage, your rules won't sync automatically. Local storage has better limits for storage so your problem will be solved.

We are working on a new feature to sync your data across devices using which you can keep using local storage for better limits and sync will be handled by the new feature.

Feel free to ask on contact@requestly.in if you have any questions.